# How do I output a webpage that contains MathML to PDF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, mathml

My web application displays MathML embedded in HTML using the MathPlayer plugin. I need to output to PDF. I have PDF components (Dynamic PDF, ABCpdf), but they don't know how to parse the MathML, of course.

Is there a library that can help me translate the MathML to an image or something that I can feed to the PDF components on the fly in the web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design Science has a command line Windows executable (also available as a DLL) that will convert all of the MathML in a document to EPS for use in PDF. It's the Document Composer, which is part of the [MathFlow SDK](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathflow/mf_components.htm). Contact us if you're interested in more info or an evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I have also found another PDF component that supports MathML called [AHFormatter](http://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf50/ahf5top.htm). I have not tried it, but it apparently works very well.